# DialogFragment fill screen on phone

Tags: android, fullscreen, fill, android-dialogfragment

I am using a DialogFragment and would like to know if there is a simple way of specifying the dialog to use full screen on normal/small size device(phone). Example of what I want to achieve is confirmation/permission dialog shown on Google Play after you select to Install app.

[image]

Comment: Just curious. How do you determine if it's a phone or a table?

Comment: I'm not aware of any defined way of determining difference it depends on implementation. My question is to show full screen dialog on normal/small screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dialog fragment embedding depends on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996217/dialog-fragment-embedding-depends-on-device)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to fill the screen with a DialogFragment you simply can change the theme. Use for full screen android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light and for non-fullscreen dialogs use
android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog;

Use these values in the call to:

setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog); // as an example

I call this method at the end of the onCreate().

Hope this helps
Jasper

Answer (score 2):

In Tablet, show dialog in a normal way.

```
DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

In Phone, add DialogFragment to the layout as normal fragment in Activity's onCreate().

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
        ft.add(R.id.embedded, newFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/embedded"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

Note: Fragment embedded by <Fragment>Tag doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There has been the same question (with the exact diagram!) and answer (by the one who ask it.) The answer is a valid one too taking advantage of the resource folder categorization. [Dialog fragment embedding depends on device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10996217/319058)