# Android - How use Fragment as Dialog or Activity depending on device

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog

I'm very new to Android programming and I'm stuck at a point where I want to finish my UI development.
The picture in this question simply explains my problem:
[Dialog fragment embedding depends on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996217/dialog-fragment-embedding-depends-on-device)

I want to create a reusable UI component with a Layout (probably LinearLayout or Relative Layout). Depending on the screen size (Tablet vs. Phone) I want to open the UI component in a Dialog or in a separate Activity.

Can anyone of you give me an advice how to achieve this?

Comment: user viewpager with fragment and give margin from all size to viewpager

Comment: This is not the right kind of question for StackOverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In the activity you want to use fragment type :**

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
//fragment class name : DFragment
DFragment dFragment = new DFragment();
            // Show DialogFragment
            dFragment.show(fm, "Welcome to dialog fragment!!");
```

**Now create a class DFragment and type :**

```
public class DFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogfragment, container,
            false);
    getDialog().setTitle("DialogFragment Tutorial");        
    // Do something else
    return rootView;
}
}
```

**dialogfragment.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/welcome" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio you can create a new `master/detail` activity to see how they resolve this.

What you could do is to create a layout with 2 configs, one for phone and other for tablets (adding width attributes for example). In the tablet layout you can add the `FrameLayout` where you are going to host the fragment.

In the `onCreate()` of the activity you can check if that `FrameLayout` exits. If it does set a variable to true `fragmentView = true` and check that where you are creating the fragment or launching the activity.